# Seeding with Faker & four random words predefined

Tags: laravel, faker, laravel-seeding

I use Faker for the first time with Laravel. I can not find anywhere to solve my problem.

2D "," 3D "or" common "with 20% chance for" web "," 2D "," 3D "and 40% For "common".

Is it possible to do this with Faker?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `randomElement` method:

```php
$faker->randomElement(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```

Comment: Helpful answer for Yii2 :P